# SonarQube LDAP Plugin StartTLS

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-plugin

We're using SonarQube 5.6.6 with LDAP Plugin 2.2.0 to authenticate users against our Active Directory server. This is working fine for non-SSL/StartTLS connections.

I saw that with version 2.1 there is a new option available to enable StartTLS.

When I add the following line to my sonar.properties

```
ldap.StartTLS=true
```

I get the following exception in my log files:

```
2017.07.18 15:48:25 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapException: Unable to open LDAP connection
        at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapContextFactory.testConnection(LdapContextFactory.java:211) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapRealm.init(LdapRealm.java:63) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.server.user.SecurityRealmFactory.start(SecurityRealmFactory.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320) ~[sonar-core-5.6.6.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141) ~[sonar-core-5.6.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel4.start(PlatformLevel4.java:655) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:216) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:190) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:113) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: StartTLS failed
        at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapContextFactory.createInitialDirContext(LdapContextFactory.java:124) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapContextFactory.createBindContext(LdapContextFactory.java:96) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapContextFactory.testConnection(LdapContextFactory.java:207) ~[na:na]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.startHandshake(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:353) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.negotiate(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:217) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.ext.StartTlsResponseImpl.negotiate(StartTlsResponseImpl.java:170) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapContextFactory.createInitialDirContext(LdapContextFactory.java:122) ~[na:na]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        ... 52 common frames omitted
2017.07.18 15:48:25 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
```

I thought that I will probably have to provide a truststore, so I added

```
sonar.web.https.truststoreFile=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.6.6/conf/mycacert.jks
sonar.web.https.truststorePass=<password>
sonar.web.https.truststoreType=JKS
```

but I still get the same exception. (It seems that this option is for HTTPS connections anyway.)

**So how do I configure LDAP+StartTLS correctly?**

**EDIT:**

I've found the `docker-compose.yml` in the author's [github repository](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-ldap/blob/5a0c89fb6aec59511dca47f80b5c3037b7c0f157/docker-compose.yml). It seems like he's loading the LDAP's certificates by setting this environment variable:

```
SONARQUBE_WEB_JVM_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/root/keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

I did the same with my keystore but with the same results as before. I tried exporting it in the `sonar` user's `.profile` as well as putting it in the `sonar.properties` file.

I found [another post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/38lJ6NPIlyg) where someone got it working by loading the file as a `trustStore` instead of a `keyStore`. Again, I get the same exception as before regardless if I put it in the user's environment or the `sonar.properties` file.

Btw. this is how I created the keystore file:

```
keytool -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <alias> -file <cert> -keystore /usr/local/sonarqube-5.6.6/conf/mycacert.jks -storepass <password>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand [this thread](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/17) correctly, `SONARQUBE_WEB_JVM_OPTS` is not supported anymore in 5.6.6.

I got it working anyway by just adding the trust store to the following line in the `sonar.properties` file

```
sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.6.6/conf/mycacert.jks
```